# Is there a C# equivalent to the Java Selector class?

Tags: c#

Is there a C# equivalent to the Java Selector class? In the .Net framework or opensource.

This is the [java.nio.channels.Selector](http://doc.java.sun.com/DocWeb/api/java.nio.channels.Selector) class.

Thanks

Comment: It might be useful to say why you want to use it in .Net code - it may be the case that there may be a different way to achieve the result you're after, in the .Net world

Comment: A more detailed discussion is available at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181322/net-equvalent-of-javas-nio-selector][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181322/net-equvalent-of-javas-nio-selector

Answer (score 0):

Not really... the closest match would be an extension method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: The original question covers an I/O API, whereas this answer discusses a programming language mechanism.  Is the link correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess there's [Socket.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx) or [WaitHandle.WaitAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190233%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but the NIO architecture of Java is totally different to the asynchronous model of I/O in .NET so there's really no direct correlation between the two.